# Merging two files with awk and changing last column for duplicates

Tags: file, join, awk, merge

I have two tab-delimited text files. I want to create an output file that has all the lines in file 1. However if the value in column 1 in file 1 matches column 1 in file 2, I would like the value in column 3 for that row to change from a 0 to a 1. Currently all values in column 3 of file 1 are 0s.

file 1:

```
A2M GO:0051056  0
A2ML1   GO:0052548  0
A4GALT  GO:0006486  0
```

file 2

```
A2M GO:0051056  1
A2ML1   GO:0052548  1
AAAS    GO:0006486  1
```

Desired output:

```
A2M GO:0051056  1
A2ML1   GO:0052548  1
A4GALT  GO:0006486  0
```

Please let me know it the question is unclear. Awk answers are preferred unless there is a simple alternative way to do it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3;next}$1 in a{$3=a[$1]}7' file2 file1
```